# How to change the Yii2 CSS?

Tags: css, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I know, it’s silly, but I really don’t know what to do at this point.

I tried to create a new folder in the frontend and had a structure like this:

```
themes
        test
              assets
                    css
                      bootstrap.css (i took a css file that contain bootstrap 4.1 and have in it a theme from bootswatch.com)
              views
                    layouts
                        main.php (i copy it from views folder and added use frontend\themes\test\TestAsset with the change of
AppAsset::register($this); to TestAsset::register($this);)
              TestAsset.php (i copied the content from the AppAsset file) In config -> main.php i added
```

```
'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'pathMap' => [
                    '@app/views' => '@frontend/themes/test/views'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

The theme that I wanted from the bootswatch.com was applied (it made some mess in the navbar, img-thumbnail and caption class), but I was thinking I could just edit them to make everything ok. But every change that I tried was not applied, not even the body background-color.

When I needed to add something, I used a class of my own:

```
$this->registerCssFile(Yii::getAlias(’@web’).’/css/library.css’);
```

and it worked.

At this point, I don’t know how to edit the css of the yii2 or how to add another one that I could use and personalize.

Comment: if you are trying to integrate a theme you should create you own `AssetBundle` class add all your `css`, `js` and `dependency` of the scripts in the class, and register it via layout. although it looks like you have used the `AssetBundle`, you should add that particular class too along with your `layout/main.php`

Comment: is it ok that the second code fragment has more `]`s than `[`s?